# Повторный .submit() после return false;

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Всем привет.

Столкнулся с проблемой. Имеется форма с id="sbmt1". И есть, допустим, некая проверка на что-то при ее сабмите, в случае отказа происходит:

```
            $('#sbmt1').submit(function() {
                return false;
            });
```

Но страница не должна перезагружаться. После успешного выполнения проверки пользователем он должен повторно отправить форму:

```
$('#sbmt1').submit();
```

Но сабмит уже не срабатывает, сопровождается каким-то странным пропуском строки над формой. Пытался сделать сабмит через .live() и .on("submit") - не работает. Не подскажите, как мне "воскресить" сабмит? Заранее спасибо. )

UPD: На аякс нет возможности перенести все, логика огромная, уже написана и реализована.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('#sbmt1').submit(function(event) {
            if (проверка) {
               alert("Форма отработала но не отправилась");
               event.preventDefault();
            }
 });
```

Пояснение: запускаем сабмит формы. В if добавь проверку, например, на пустоту какого-либо поля. Если поле пустое - выполняем какие-то действия и не перезагружаем форму. Если в if не зашло - форма перезагрузится.